# Cheap guitar - steel strings

Tags: acoustic-guitar

I recently pulled out this really cheap guitar and tuned it up to start playing. My friend who is a guitarist recommended that I replace the cheap plastic strings with steel strings for a better sound. I bought .11 to .52 steel strings but I am struggling to insert them into the guitar. I have also removed the plastic strings and have no idea if and how to temporarily put them back so I can continue playing. Help! How do I re string this guitar! I haven’t found any help at all on the internet, hope someone can answer my question.

Comment: Sorry to say, your friend gave you some bad advice. Probably your best bet at this point is to read Tetsujin's answer and then take your guitar to be strung correctly by a professional with **new** nylon strings - most stores that sell guitars will string a guitar for you, for a fee.

Comment: Thank you so much! I’ve literally been going crazy not being able to play :(

Comment: Just out of interest, how could you **NOT** find instructions on the internet?  google "how to string acoustic guitar with plastic strings" gives hundreds of hits, including very nice YouTube tutorials

Comment: Your friend's advice is a perfect example of how not enough information can cause a lot of damage. The guitar isn't designed for the additional stress of steel strings if it originally was designed for nylon strings.

Answer (score 5):

General rule is - don't put steel strings on a classical guitar.

1. You'll ruin the neck, unless it has a truss-rod you can adjust.
2. If the bridge is meant to have the strings tied on rather than ball-end, you'll struggle.

Broadly speaking 'classical' & 'folk' guitars are different beasts & the strings cannot be interchanged.

BTW, the distinction is not "cheap plastic" vs "expensive steel" the two are made for entirely different purposes.